# stuck on minimax algorithm

Tags: algorithm, chess, minimax

I'm attempting my first chess engine. Anyone who is familiar with the subject will know a thing or two about the minimax algorithm. I need to generate a combination of every possible move on the board for every piece. I've looked up a number of examples but can't get mine to work. I don't know what I am doing wrong. I'm just focused on the generation of every possible moves, to a certain depth, to get the leaf nodes.

The problem I'm facing is that my current implementation is making one move for black then making continuous moves for white without letting the black move again when it should be alternating back and fourth. I use Direct recursion to and loop through the available moves. I expect the function to start from the top every time but the direct recursion isn't working the way I thought it would. The loop keeps getting iterated through without starting from the top of the function and I don't know why. This means that the getAvailableMoves(maximizer) isn't being called every time like it should be (I think).

if anyone could point out what I'm doing wrong it would be appreciated.

```
public int miniMax(int depth, boolean maximizer)
{
    if(depth == 0) { return 1234; }
    int countMoves = 0;

        Map<ChessPiece, Position> availableMoves = getAvailableMoves(maximizer);
        int bestMove = 0;
        for(Map.Entry<ChessPiece, Position> entry : availableMoves.entrySet()) 
        {

            ChessPiece piece = entry.getKey();
            Position pos = entry.getValue();
            piece.move(board, pos.getX(), pos.getY());
            maximizer = !maximizer;
            miniMax(depth-1, maximizer);
        }

    return 1234;
}
```

Comment: One issue: you need to remove `maximizer = !maximizer` and instead pass the negation on the next line: `miniMax(depth-1, !maximizer)`. Otherwise, every even numbered iteration of the loop will end up with the wrong value.

Comment: Another issue: it looks like you're mutating the `board` (since it doesn't get passed in). That's okay, but it means you need to undo the move again as you pop back up your recursion stack. (This includes un-capturing pieces, un-promoting pawns, or un-castling.) An alternative is to clone the board, make the move, and pass the clone into the next call. This is conceptually much simpler, so I'd recommend starting there.

Comment: Finally, I'd recommend putting a line at the top of the function that prints the values of `depth` and `maximizer`. This will make it easier to see the chain of calls and make sure things are happening as you expect them to.

Comment: Thanks smarkx. The "maximizer != maximizer" seems to be working correctly. However, your way is much cleaner and should work except that the top of the function is not performing the direct recursion every time. the foreach loop just continues on without starting from the top of the function again. This seems to be my main issue. Each time the miniMax method is called again it should start at the top but instead it just keeps continuing thorught the loop. I can;t for the life of me figure out why.

Comment: @LukeJames that's not correct, it enters into recursion on every iteration of the for loop, so it does depth first recursion instead of breadth first

Comment: Can you please elaborate Patrick? From my understanding it should do the recursion for each iteration of the foreach loop. I believe that should end up getting the leaf nodes.

Comment: Yes, it gets leaf nodes but not in the order you'd expect, or want from a minimax algorithm.

Comment: I tried to follow many different examples of minimax and I thought that was the way it was supposed to work. What exactly am I doing wrong?

Comment: @LukeJames You're mistaken about what's happening here, so please do as I suggested and add a print statement to the top of the function so you can see what's actually happening. (You're describing something impossible, like function calls jumping into the middle of a loop before executing the lines of code above it.) Add some debug output, take a moment to understand it, and then if you still have a question, paste that output here and ask for further help. (At some point, you'll also need to fix the mutable `board` issue I pointed out.)

Comment: @smarx I have tried adding print functions before the loop and inside. I can clearly see what is happening. Black moves first, followed by white. Then white keeps moving over and over again, skipping black each time until the loop is done. I have stepped through with the debugger and it is not reaching the top of the function for each itteration of the loop as I expect it would.

I have the project on github if you would like to take a look. https://github.com/ljames604/LukeChess

Comment: I can't find any function called `miniMax` in that repo.

Comment: @LukeJames If you've already added debug output, share that version of the code, and share the output so you can get help understanding it.

Comment: My apologizes. I didn't push the latest version of the code. It is all there now. I will post the output of the function right now. THanks.

Comment: here is the output half way through the algorithm. You can see that the player on top (white) keeps making moves but black (on the bottom) never makes any.

https://gyazo.com/b1078fbf5d6db94e04ce5c869ff9a3e7

Comment: It looks like you're passing in a depth of 2, so isn't this expected? At depth == 2, black tries its first available move. At depth == 1, white tries its first available move. At depth == 0, we just return 1234, so we're back up to white's second available move, then white's third available move, etc. After white tries all its available moves, we go back up to depth == 2 and black attempts its second available move.

Comment: Now, because of the mutating board issue I've pointed out, everything beyond a color's first attempted move is broken. (The board will be in an invalid state, showing all the moves that have been considered so far.)

Comment: I can't believe how stupid I am. Thank you for pointing that out. It seems that the reason the direct recursion was not working is because I had set it to only a depth of two. I will review your other suggestions and implement the undo move functionality. Thank you very much.